# Linq query to order a list based on date and get distinct

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list as shown below:

```
List<MyObjects> list:
list[0] - Id: 1; RefId:101; Date:22/06/2016
list[1] - Id: 2; RefId:102; Date:24/06/2016
list[2] - Id: 3; RefId:101; Date:26/06/2016
list[3] - Id: 4; RefId:103; Date:28/06/2016
```

I need a linq query,which gets me distinct based on RefId having latest date, something like this:

```
List<MyObjects> newList:
list[0] - Id: 3; RefId:101; Date:26/06/2016
list[1] - Id: 2; RefId:102; Date:24/06/2016
list[2] - Id: 4; RefId:103; Date:28/06/2016
```

Here RefId-101 is repeated but its first date value is old, hence removed.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Solution by @Enigmativity is the best in my understanding, since you receive the result as IEnumerable<T> instead of IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>>

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Linq Group by `RefId` then order each group by `Date` then take first out of each group :

```
list.GroupBy(x => x.RefId).Select(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault());
```

OR using Query-Syntax:

```
List<MyObjects> results = (from x in list
                            group x by x.RefId into grp
                            select grp.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).FirstOrDefault()
                            ).ToList();
```

Comment: Awesome!! Thanks buddy

Answer (score 4):

You can use `GroupBy` to group by `RefId`, then sort this groups by `Date` and take the first ones:

```
var result = list.GroupBy(o => o.RefId)
      .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(gx => gx.Date).First())
      .ToList();
```

Since you want the *latest* `Date`, you need to `OrderByDescending`.

Comment: @ René Vogt My mistake, apology, this too will result in correct solution as expected, deleting my last comment, somewhere I missed usage of First in my code

Answer (score 2):

I think it is best to avoid calling `.FirstOrDefault()`. Here's an alternative:

```
var newList =
    list
        .GroupBy(x => x.RefId)
        .SelectMany(x => x.OrderByDescending(y => y.Date).Take(1))
        .ToList();
```

Comment: Why the FirstOrDefault shall be avoided, if there's any data, then Take(1) will do what FirstOrDefault (fetching the first value)

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - There is a difference; `.FirstOrDefault()` always produces a value whereas `.Take(1)` produces either 0 or 1 value. `.Take(1)` can also be generalized easily as `.Take(n)` so if you get used to using it is can be more powerful. Also, in this case there is guaranteed to be a value so `.First()` would work, so using `.FirstOrDefault()` is a bit sloppy.

Comment: Got that my initial impression was that you are not even in favor of First(), I understand .FirstOrDefault() may not be the best usage

Comment: @MrinalKamboj - No, I don't like `.First` either. :-)